# How is my 2.4GHz Wi-Fi working with my 2.4GHz Bluetooth(pixel buds) on my phone?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, bluetooth

I just want to know how this working for the sake of my sanity.

I have a dual band [D-LINK DIR-819 router](https://www.dlink.com/en/products/dir-819-wireless-ac750-dual-band-router) (which has both 2.4GHz and 5GHz bands). I am connecting my [Google Pixel Buds Series A](https://store.google.com/gb/product/pixel_buds_a_series_specs?hl=en-GB) on my [Samsung Galaxy A31](https://www.samsung.com/africa_en/smartphones/galaxy-a/galaxy-a31-black-128gb-sm-a315fzkvxfe/) along with the 2.4GHz WiFi.

And the funny thing is that they both work fine.

**How are they both working on the 2.4GHz ?**

**There cannot be Bluetooth and WiFi on the 2.4GHz spectrum right ?**

Is it something to do with the fact that my router is a dual-band router ? I used to have a [D-LINK DIR 505](https://www.techradar.com/reviews/pc-mac/networking-and-wi-fi/modem-routers/d-link-dir-505-1122767/review) with only 2.4GHz where the Wi-Fi would basically stop transmitting when it was used simultaneously with Bluetooth.

**What has changed here ?**

Thanks

Comment: "There can be only one device on the 2.4GHz spectrum right?" - Incorrect.

Comment: @Ramhound I have corrected that. But there can't be Bluetooth and WiFi both on 2.4GHz, right ?

Comment: Your are mistaken.

Comment: 2.4GHz is a free band that is used by Wifi Bluetooth, baby phones, and so on. Furthermore 2.4GHz Wifi is not one frequency but one frequency range (2.412 GHz - 2.462 GHz and even more in some countries). So even for Wifi there are least three channels which do not intersect regarding the used frequencies.

Comment: @Ramhound Would be nice if you could elaborate

Comment: @Robert What I can't make sense of this - With my older router I am unable to use both Bluetooth and Wifi(2.4GHZ), but then how does it work with the new one. **What can be so  special about the new one ?**

Comment: Your router has nothing to to with if you can use Bluetooth or not. The phone is the one who has to manage Bluetooth and Wifi so that they don't disturb each other too much. In my opinion it is just coincidence that it now works.

Comment: @ng.newbie - 2.4 GHz WiFi has multiple channels, while your microwave, Bluetooth, and 2.4 GHz cordless phone might cause a small amount inference at the 2.4 GHz band they are likely are NOT running at the same channel as your WIFI gateway and thus the interference is strictly NOT a problem.  You have also received an answer to your question that explains in detail the how your understanding isn't correct. (WiFi i.e. 802.11).  There are huge differences between WiFi 5 and whatever version your old router used (page you linked to contained zero specifications).

Comment: @ng.newbie nothing special. Bluetooth and wifi can already run simultaneously for decades, long before the advent of 5GHz wifi. Just enable bluetooth and go around you'll see myriads of bluetooth devices (mostly headphones) being opened, and at the same time and position you can see so many active wifi networks

Answer (score 0):

> How are they both working on the 2.4GHz ?

They use many multiple-access methods like [TDMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-division_multiple_access), [FDMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-division_multiple_access), [CDMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-division_multiple_access), [OFDMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_frequency-division_multiple_access)... for sharing the same spectrum

> There cannot be Bluetooth and WiFi on the 2.4GHz spectrum right ?

Incorrect. There can be multiple devices in the same WiFi or Bluetooth network, and multiple networks at the same time. Besides 2.4 GHz, 5 GHz (or more correctly 5.8 GHz), 60 GHz... are frequencies in the [ISM band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISM_radio_band) that are free to use for any purpose without registration (that's an over-simplification) so lots of other devices use them like microwave ovens, wireless phones, Zigbee..., not only WiFi or Bluetooth

That's not to say they all transmit at the same time. Some kind of [medium access control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_access_control) needs to be used, such as [CSCD/MA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-sense_multiple_access_with_collision_detection). Put it very simply, a WiFi router needs to detect if the transmission was messed up due to another device's transmission in the same frequency at the same time then it needs to resolve that in some way at a later time

Comment: Hey thanks for explaining. Can you please tell me then why some routers can work with 2.4GHz and Bluetooth and why some can't ? I mean my older router(DLINK DIR 505) wouldn't transmit WiFi if I had used Bluetooth on my phone. This is what is confusing me.

Comment: @ng.newbie it means the router or the phone is broken